# Vue: Check which checkbox is checked and send along different data depending

Tags: javascript, vue.js

A radio form conditionally disabled by another checkbox. One radio button can send along true:false and the other has an input which sends some data.

What check can I do to determine which radio is checked and how to send along true:false or the data.

```
  <input type="radio" id="one"
  value="Voicemail"
  v-bind:disabled="!checked"
  v-model="checkedValue">
  <label for="one">Voicemail</label>

  <input type="radio" id="two"
  value="Destination"
  v-bind:disabled="!checked"
  v-model="checkedValue">

  <label for="two">Destination</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="destinationNumber" v-bind:disabled="!checked">
  <button class="button" type="submit" name="button" v-bind:disabled="!checked">Submit</button>

data () {
  return {
      checked: '',
      checkedValue: '',
      destinationNumber: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  handleExtensionFormSubmit () {
    const postData = {
      destination: this.checkedValue = 'Destination' ? this.destinationNumber : '',
      voicemail: this.checkedValue = 'Voicemail' ? true : ''
    }

this.$http.put(/someUrl)
```

My request should look like this:

```
destination: 666,
voicemail: false
```

Or

```
destination: '',
voicemail: true
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code right now is your post object.

```
postData = {
  destination: this.checkedValue = 'Destination' ? this.destinationNumber : '',
  voicemail: this.checkedValue = 'Voicemail' ? true : ''
}
```

`this.checkedValue = 'Destination'` isn't checking anything it is setting the value of `checkedValue` to Destination which will always evaluate to true. You need to change both of these to `==`. Also, if you want to return false for Voicemail you need `?true:false` not `?true:''`. I'm not sure exactly what all your code is supposed to do, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my issue. I don't actually want to send along a false value, just an empty string so this works. Thank you.

Any chance you might know how to get a dynamic initial value tied to the radio and inputs? Computed property with getters? But then what?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio-1 addresses this. You can bind the value of an input to some variable `<input type="radio" id="one"  :value="radioOneValue"  v-model="checkedValue">`. Also, extra tip you don't need `v-bind:` you just need the `:` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: @DevinChaves also, don't forget to click the checkbox if this answers your question.